FUSE high-level ioctl function receiving null parameters
Working on a FUSE filesystem. When implementing the ioctl handler both of these parameters seem to be NULL no matter what I do. I'm unsure if I'm misunderstanding what the paramters represent or incorrectly invoking the syscall. Below I have my ioctl method handler using the high-level FUSE API and the user application code invoking the syscall. Any suggestions how to debug or fix would be appreciated. Thanks!
FUSE:
static int cu_fuse_ioctl(const char* path_, int cmd, void* arg, struct fuse_file_info*, unsigned int flags, void* data) {
   if(arg == NULL) {
      printf("arg was null!\n");
   }

   if(data == NULL) {
      printf("data was null!\n");
   }

   return 0;
}

USER APP:
int main() {
    const char *dev_path = "/home/theassembler1/src/view/.spec_dev";
    const char *message = "test";
    int fd;
    int ret;
    char buffer[256];

    fd = open(dev_path, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("Failed to open device");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d %s", CMD_NUMBER, message);

    ret = ioctl(fd, CMD_NUMBER, buffer);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("ioctl failed");
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("ioctl command %d sent successfully with message: %s\n", CMD_NUMBER, message);

    close(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


It might be helpful if you show how you to compile and run this for wider audience.  You hard-code a path to a file in your home directory.  Consider accepting that via an environment variable and/or a command line argument so others can run your program unmodified.

@AllanWin I just link to the libfuse library. For running just mount onto any directory. Surely the user application example doesn't need an explanation...

Perhaps this ioctl is considered by the kernel as an output command rather than input? See libfuse ioctl example https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/ioctl.h#L34

@OrenKishon nice catch. That is probably the issue. I'll use the corrected cmd and check if that fixes it. I thought the kernel would just foward the args and let the device interpret the cmd...
